# Widget with content provider; impossible to use ReadPermission?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-contentprovider

So I've just implemented a widget for my app. It gets its data from the database through my `ContentProvider`. I define my own read/write-permissions in my manifest, state that I use them (doesn't seem to make a difference), and require them in the content provider:

```
<!-- Define my permissions for the provider -->
<permission
    android:name="com.nononsenseapps.notepad.permissions.read"
    android:description="@string/permission_read_desc"
    android:label="@string/permission_read_label"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.PERSONAL_INFO"
    android:protectionLevel="normal" />
<permission
    android:name="com.nononsenseapps.notepad.permissions.write"
    android:description="@string/permission_write_desc"
    android:label="@string/permission_write_label"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.PERSONAL_INFO"
    android:protectionLevel="normal" />
......
<uses-permission android:name="com.nononsenseapps.notepad.permissions.read" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.nononsenseapps.notepad.permissions.write" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />
......
<provider
        android:name=".NotePadProvider"
        android:authorities="com.nononsenseapps.NotePad"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:readPermission="com.nononsenseapps.notepad.permissions.read"
        android:syncable="true"
        android:writePermission="com.nononsenseapps.notepad.permissions.write" >
        <grant-uri-permission android:pathPattern=".*" />
    </provider>
```

I update my widget through a `Service` (as per the widget tutorial):

```
    <!-- List Widget -->
    <receiver android:name="com.nononsenseapps.notepad.widget.ListWidgetProvider" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/listwidgetinfo" />
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.nononsenseapps.notepad.widget.ListWidgetService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />
```

And that `Service` in turn does this (with a bunch of code not included):

```
/**
 * This is the service that provides the factory to be bound to the collection
 * service.
 */
public class ListWidgetService extends RemoteViewsService {

@Override
public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
    return new StackRemoteViewsFactory(this.getApplicationContext(), intent);
}
}

/**
 * This is the factory that will provide data to the collection widget.
 */
class StackRemoteViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {

public StackRemoteViewsFactory(Context context, Intent intent) {
    mContext = context;
    observer = new ListChecker(null);
    mAppWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
            AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
}
public void onDataSetChanged() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onDataSetChanged");
    // Refresh the cursor
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.close();
    }

    // Get widget settings
    SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getSharedPreferences(
            ListWidgetConfigure.getSharedPrefsFile(mAppWidgetId),
            mContext.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (settings != null) {
        String listWhere = settings.getString(ListWidgetConfigure.LIST_WHERE, null);
        listId  = settings.getLong(ListWidgetConfigure.LIST_ID, -1);
        String sortOn = settings.getString(ListWidgetConfigure.SORT_ON, NotePad.Notes.ALPHABETIC_ASC_ORDER);

        mCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
                NotePadProvider.CONTENT_VISIBLE_URI, PROJECTION, listWhere, null,
                sortOn);
    }
}
}
```

So here's the problem: when I add the widget to the homescreen, a `SecurityException` is immediately thrown inside the `onDataSetChanged()` method when I try to query the provider. This appears to be because the homescreen does not hold the permission to read my content provider. My intuition was that it would not be a problem since my own app has the permission, and the service is obviously a part of my app.

Everything works beautifully if I remove the ReadPermission requirement from the provider. But that seems like a security problem because then any app can access the provider without the user having to approve anything.

So is there a way to use a provider with a ReadPermission with a widget? Or are you forced to use an unsecured exported provider?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem, did you find any solution yet? If so, could you please describe as an answer how you fixed it?

Comment: Sadly no. Found no solution so I just removed the required permission :(

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was able to find the answer [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/yj4xEkZDWhQ), credit goes to Kostya Vasilyev.

While the context is actually correct, it is bound to the wrong process.

So the key is to do this:

```
public void onDataSetChanged() {
     // Revert back to our process' identity so we can work with our
     // content provider
     final long identityToken = Binder.clearCallingIdentity();

     // Update your cursor or whatever here
     // ...

     // Restore the identity - not sure if it's needed since we're going
     // to return right here, but it just *seems* cleaner
     Binder.restoreCallingIdentity(identityToken);
}
```

Comment: Perfect response. This solves the problem, even without setting read/write permissions on the contentprovider, just using it with exported set to "false".

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, it's because you are using the context of the widget, which will be that of the homescreen.  Try the following line in your code:

```
mCursor = ListWidgetService.this.getContentResolver().query(
            NotePadProvider.CONTENT_VISIBLE_URI, PROJECTION, listWhere, null,
            sortOn);
```

Note how I replaced the `mContext.`.  A Service is a Context of its own, which should have the correct permission, given your manifest.

Comment: Actually, if you look at the code you see that the context being passed to the RemoteViewsFactory is exactly what you suggest. However, your answer made me investigate further and I was able to find the solution! Posted it as an answer.

Comment: Indeed, you're right, not sure how I missed that :) But I'm glad it put you on the right track anyway :)