# RemoteViewsFactory grantUriPermission to fetch data

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-appwidget

have an AppWidget with a Listview that I want to populate with a RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory.

I have the following error

> E/AndroidRuntime(1203): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission
>   Denial: reading com.crbin1.myapp.data.ProviderLTD uri
>   content://com.crbin1.myapp.data.ProviderLTD/TB_WIDGET3P from pid=413,
>   uid=10013 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()

If I export ProviderLTD (my content provider) in manifest it works, but I'd like to avoid to export it.

The other solution is grantUriPermission(). I set grantUriPermissions to true in manifest, but now I don't understand where in my code I have to grant the permissions.

```
public class Widget3pService extends RemoteViewsService {
       @Override
        public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
           return new StackRemoteViewsFactory(this.getApplicationContext(), intent);
        }
    }


    class StackRemoteViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {
        private List<ObjW3Task> mWidgetItems = new ArrayList<ObjW3Task>();
        private Context mContext;
        private int mAppWidgetId;

        public StackRemoteViewsFactory(Context context, Intent intent) {
            mContext = context;
            mAppWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        }

        public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
            // use mWidgetItems to populate ListView
            // fillInIntent for listeners
            return myRemoteViews;
        }

        public void onDataSetChanged() {
            mWidgetItems = new ArrayList<ObjW3Task>();
            // create mWidgetItems by accessing my ContentProvider class
        }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

not sure if this is still relevant; I found it works on mine, by setting "android:exported = true":

```
<provider android:name="WeatherDataProvider" android:exported="true">
```

See this:
[Android Permission denial in Widget RemoteViewsFactory for Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187284/android-permission-denial-in-widget-remoteviewsfactory-for-content)