# SecurityException with grantUriPermission when sharing a file with FileProvider

Tags: android, permissions, securityexception, android-fileprovider

I have two applications.  I'm trying to share a file from application A to application B using a FileProvider.  Application A calls the insert method on a ContentProvider in Application B to insert a record. The data inserted includes the Uri to the file I want to share from App A.  The ContentProvider in App B would then try to read the shared file from App A.
Since I'm not using an Intent to share the file, I'm calling `Context.grantUriPermission` in App A to allow the read (and at times write):

```
mContext.grantUriPermission(MyPackageName, contentUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

However, executing this line gives me (Names changed to protect the innocent):

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Uid 10066 does not have permission to uri content://au.com.example.AppA.fileprovider/MyFolder/MyFileName
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1322)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.grantUriPermission(ActivityManagerNative.java:2374)
at android.app.ContextImpl.grantUriPermission(ContextImpl.java:1371)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.grantUriPermission(ContextWrapper.java:400)
at etc...
```

App A has the following in the Manifest file:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="au.com.example.AppA.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true"
    android:readPermission="au.com.example.READ_CONTENT"
    android:writePermission="au.com.example.WRITE_CONTENT" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
</provider>
```

filepaths.xml has:

```
<paths>
    <files-path
        name="MyFolder"
        path="MyFolder/" />
</paths>
```

Both App A and App B have the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="au.com.example.READ_CONTENT" />
<uses-permission android:name="au.com.example.WRITE_CONTENT" />
```

I've tried defining the permissions in both apps. They are both signed with the same debug signature:

```
<permission
    android:name="au.com.example.READ_CONTENT"
    android:permissionGroup="MyGroup"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" >
</permission>
<permission
    android:name="au.com.example.WRITE_CONTENT"
    android:permissionGroup="MyGroup"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" >
</permission>
```

The actual path the file ends up in is:

```
/data/data/au.com.example.AppA/files/MyFolder
```

At this point I'm stumped. I don't know why I can't grant permission for a file I just created within the same application.  So my questions are: Why am I getting this exception and how can I successfully grant permission to App B?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, after a week and a lot of trial and error, it seems the answer is to not specify permissions.  So the App A Manifest should instead contain:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="au.com.example.AppA.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
</provider>
```

ie, I removed the read and write permissions. My initial understanding, and failing to find documentation that said otherwise, was these were necessary to restrict access.  However, I've found they actually interfere and cause `Context.grantUriPermission` to fail. Access is limited already.

To complete the picture, and answer the second part of my question, I found the following:

[Android Permission denial in Widget RemoteViewsFactory for Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187284/android-permission-denial-in-widget-remoteviewsfactory-for-content)

I had to add:

```
final long token = Binder.clearCallingIdentity();
try {
    [retrieve file here]
} finally {
    Binder.restoreCallingIdentity(token);
}
```

to the Content Provider in App B.  Otherwise it would get security errors as well.

Comment: I was also having this issue and removed the read permission from the manifest but still getting `Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{40b7b968 7764:com.google.android.gm/10018} (pid=7764, uid=10018) requires null or null`

Comment: @DiscoS2 I've seen the same thing. I found that uninstalling and reinstalling the application fixed it.  I haven't checked but I suspect there is some kind of caching of the manifest going on.

Comment: If you aren't using permissions with Signature level isn't your application exposed to external threats to read any file just having the correct Uri?

Comment: @Toochka temporary permission is granted under very specific circumstances allowing you to limit access.  Check out the documentation on [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html).

Answer (score -4):

The first problem in your code is exported attribute set to false. Please change it to true as,

```
<provider
android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
android:authorities="au.com.example.AppA.fileprovider"
android:exported="true"
android:readPermission="au.com.example.READ_CONTENT"
android:writePermission="au.com.example.WRITE_CONTENT" >
</provider>
```

The second thing you have to do is, If external application App B is using content provider in App A.Then in App A manifest file mention permission as,

```
<permission
android:name="au.com.example.READ_CONTENT"
 >
</permission>
<permission
android:name="au.com.example.WRITE_CONTENT"
 >
</permission>
```

and in App B mention uses-permission as,

```
<uses-permission android:name="au.com.example.READ_CONTENT" />
<uses-permission android:name="au.com.example.WRITE_CONTENT" />
```

Please let me know whether your problem has solved or not. If not please send your entire code. I will try to find the problem.
Thank you.

Comment: I did end up solving this problem. Please see the accepted answer. Exported=true would allow access to any application with the listed permissions. I was trying to share from one application to another, not any application.

Comment: Do you mean temporary permissions

Comment: `FileProvider` checks for `android:exported="true"` and will throw exception.