# Instant App: RuntimeException: Unable to get provider FileProvider: SecurityException: Provider must grant uri permissions

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-fileprovider, android-instant-apps

I tried adding an instant app feature to my app, but when launching my app as an instant app I'm getting this error :

> RuntimeException: Unable to get provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider: java.lang.SecurityException: Provider must grant uri permissions

Here is how it's used in my `feature` Manifest:

```
<manifest>

    <application>

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />

        </provider>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And my instant-app `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.instantapp'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdk

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "applicationId" // same than my app's APK module
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdk
        versionCode rootProject.versionCode
        versionName rootProject.versionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation project(':feature') // app's feature
}
```

What is wrong? Thanks for your help.

**EDIT : Here is the complete logcat:**

```
02-13 17:51:28.501 28992-28992/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: package, PID: 28992
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider: java.lang.SecurityException: Provider must grant uri permissions
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6206)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5721)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5639)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1637)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Provider must grant uri permissions
                                                       at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.attachInfo(FileProvider.java:375)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6203)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5721) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5639) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1637) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831) 
02-13 17:51:28.535 28932-28944/? E/Isotope: UID: [10188]  PID: [28932] IActivityManagerProxy : Instant app: package crashed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider: java.lang.SecurityException: Provider must grant uri permissions
                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6206)
                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5721)
                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5639)
                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1637)
                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
                                             Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Provider must grant uri permissions
                                                at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.attachInfo(FileProvider.java:375)
                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6203)
                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5721) 
                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5639) 
                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1637) 
                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156) 
                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523) 
                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941) 
                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21275898/securityexception-with-granturipermission-when-sharing-a-file-with-fileprovider

Comment: @iamgopal I tried to do what's described in this thread but couldn't get it working

Comment: Well actually I don't really know where to put this code since my app crashes even before launching

Comment: I've added the logcat. I tried setting a breakpoint on a line reported in the logcat but the execution doesn't stop there...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165076/discussion-between-iamgopal-and-someday).

Comment: Please follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18249007/2550246

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [***`FileProvider`***](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html) ***isn't supported on O*** either because other apps aren't allowed to see its [**`ContentProvider`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).

I have a test app that works as an ***installed*** app but not as an ***[instant app](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/faqs.html)***. It looks like *instant apps* aren't allowed to use `grantUriPermission`(grant URI permissions) (*which makes sense given the policy that instant apps can't be visible to installed apps and `ContentProvider` is not visible*).

This means that instant apps can't retrieve pictures taken with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` (because they can't read external storage and the camera app can't write to instant apps' private storage).

Comment: It seems to be the actual problem, I solved it by removing this part of the base `Manifest` and putting it in the APK's `Manifest`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `grantUriPermissions` and `exported` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
        <provider
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider">
            <meta-data
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                />
        </provider>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).