# Error: Uid 10087 does not have permission to uri 0

Tags: android, permissions, uri

I'm studying Android.
I want to load Image from gallery..
but something is wrong

please Help....

It's similar with me   [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21275898/securityexception-with-granturipermission-when-sharing-a-file-with-fileprovider)

This is my Error code
I think It means "I can't touch my uri"
but I checked my Manifest

This is Error Code.

> **Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Uid 10087 does not have permission to uri 0 @** content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Ffile%2F116/ORIGINAL/NONE/1817194500
>                         at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1684)
>                         at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
>                         at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3101)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1518)
>                         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4225)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:757)
>                         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:744)
>                         **at com.example.z2_sooodt.syslet_2018_summer.pre_startActivity.onActivityResult(pre_startActivity.java:220)**
>                         at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6932)

This is my part of Manifest

```
<manifest...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>
.... </application
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.example.z2_sooodt.syslet_2018_summer.filepaths"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

And a part of Code

```
private Uri mImage;
private ImageView iview;
private String absoultePath;
private static final int PICK_FROM_CAMERA = 0;
private static final int PICK_FROM_ALBUM = 1;
private static final int CROP_FROM_IMAGE = 2;
public int FuckingFLAG;

private String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA};


@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

            final DialogInterface.OnClickListener cameraListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    intent.setType(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.CONTENT_TYPE);
                    intent.setData(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_ALBUM);
                }
            };

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }

    if(requestCode == PICK_FROM_ALBUM) {
            if (data == null)
                return;
            mImage = data.getData();
        Intent cropPictureIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        cropPictureIntent.setDataAndType(mImage, "image/*");
        cropPictureIntent.putExtra("output", mImage);

        cropPictureIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
        cropPictureIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);


        cropPictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        cropPictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

        startActivityForResult(cropPictureIntent, CROP_FROM_IMAGE); /*This is the Error 
(at com.example.z2_sooodt.syslet_2018_summer.pre_startActivity.onActivityResult(pre_startActivity.java:220) )  **///


    }
```

Comment: Are you doing this for an SD Card?

Comment: No. Android Virtual Device use

Answer (score -3):

What the emulator or phone API? Are you trying to grant permissions for your APP from phone preferences Settings/Apps&Notifications/YourApp/Permissions?

Comment: Here is my buid.gradle                                                                  
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.z2_sooodt.syslet_2018_summer"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28

Comment: Are you trying to grant permissions for your APP from phone preferences Settings/Apps&Notifications/YourApp/Permissions?

Comment: When I take photo using camera then doing crop is done. but when I bring a picture from gallery then Error..... Why..????????

Comment: I cheked Settings/Apps&Notifications/YourApp/Permissions .  there are Camera ,Stroage. Both are already used.

Comment: please do not post your question as an answer to the question.